# Using Canonical for Duplicate Content with friendly urls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, seo, duplicates, canonicalization

I have a rails app and in the app we are using 2 locale variables, `:en` & `:fr`

In the help section we have articles written in both language as;

```
...en/help/articles/5-booking-process #Content EN
...fr/help/articles/5-Processus-de-reservation #Content FR
```

But it creates also this;

```
...en/help/articles/5-booking-process
```

and the content is english. **BUT**, because of friendly id it also generates this url;

```
...en/help/articles/5-Processus-de-reservation
```

In this link, as `@locale` returns `:en` the content is english but the url - friendly part - is french.

I do not know how to avoid such a problem, should I add canonical or change the structure of `routes.rb`?

In `routes.rb`

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  scope "(:locale)", locale: /#{I18n.available_locales.join("|")}/ do  
    ...
    ...
    ...
  end
end
```

**PS:** This is how I use friendly url in the relevant model:

```
def to_param
  "#{id}-#{title.parameterize}"
end
```